# Skip one onblur function

Tags: javascript, function, onblur, skip

I have problem with skipping one of two onblur functions. I have control with two onblur functions and in some conditions I have to skip first onblur function. The second function was added with jquery. I can not change the first onblur function, only skip. Is there some way to do this?
Sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

If the jquery event is added after the initial onblur event, you could call event.stopPropagation or event.stopImmediatePropagation to cancel event propagation depending on the structure when skip conditions are met.